# What userland strings get automatically interned by PHP?

Tags: php, string, internals, php-internals, string-interning

I was trying to get a better understanding of PHP's internal mechanisms of [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) - more specifically:

**What are the rules PHP uses to determine whether (or not) the string created in userland will be interned**...?

I see two possibilities:

1. Only some strings are interned by PHP.
2. PHP interns all strings.

For example - in Python *(cpython)* **some, but not all** strings are interned automatically *(according to the Internet: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/ or https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/intern.html, to give some examples of sources I found)*.

I was trying to find some info about how PHP determines if the string from userland will be interned or not *(I somehow expect that strings several megabytes in size are probably excluded from interning - but are they really...?)* - but I couldn't find any.

I found this page http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/internal_types/strings/zend_strings.html, but I don't see any mention about specific rules about automatic interning.

Comment: As a rough rule, PHP interns all symbol names and string literals.

Comment: Thank you :) Are there any specific places you could point out (maybe in `php-src`) where details about this "rough rule" could be studied?